# Can read local JSON using rest assured

Tags: rest-assured

I am learning rest assured and trying to read my local javascript file. I am not sure if I can do that

This is what I am trying

```
    Response resp = get("C:/dev/testrest.js");
    assertEquals(200, resp.getStatusCode());
```

Here testrest.js is JSON

I am getting this error

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<404>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST Assured is for testing HTTP services (servers) and not for working with Javascript files. If you're looking for easily extracting values out of a JSON document you should have a look at [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) which is shipped with REST Assured (see [getting started guide](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#jsonpath)).